# Eclipse RCP dependency suddenly ignored

Tags: eclipse-plugin, dependencies, eclipse-rcp, dependency-management

I am working on an Eclipse RCP application, using Eclipse 3.5.

My problem is that when I've added a dependency between two plugins, the classes of another pluginsuddenly seem ignored and show compilation errors. Here is the setup:

- A core plugin
- A plugin M1 that depends on core
- A plugin M2 that also depends on core

When I add a dependency from M2 to M1, every class coming from "core" in M2 are shown as compilation errors.

When I remove this dependency, then everything returns to normal: the core classes used in M2 now compile correctly.

Has anybody seen this before? :-)

Thanks for your help!

As requested:

**Core manifest:**
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: mysoftware Core
*Bundle-SymbolicName: com.mycompany.mysoftware.core;singleton:=true*
Bundle-Version: 2.7.2.qualifier
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.gef,
 org.eclipse.ui.views.log,
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository,
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core,
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director,
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine,
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata,
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository,
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository,
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite,
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extensionlocation,
 org.eclipse.ecf,
 org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer,
 org.eclipse.ecf.identity,
 org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer,
 org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient,
 org.apache.commons.codec,
 org.apache.commons.httpclient,
 org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin.equinox,
 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator,
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives,
 org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin,
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse,
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 libs/jaxb-api-2.1.jar,
 libs/jaxb-impl-2.1.8.jar,
 libs/activation-1.1.jar,
 libs/persistence-api-1.0.jar,
 libs/stax-api-1.0-2.jar,
 libs/jcalendar-1.3.2.jar,
 libs/log4j-1.2.13.jar,
 libs/miglayout-3.7.jar,
 libs/xalan-2.6.0.jar,
 libs/xercesImpl-2.4.0.jar,
 libs/glazedlists-1.7.0_java15.jar,
 libs/jcommon-1.0.16.jar,
 libs/jfreechart-1.0.13-experimental.jar,
 libs/jfreechart-1.0.13-swt.jar,
 libs/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar,
 libs/swtgraphics2d.jar,
 libs/org.sf.feeling.swt.win32.extension_1.0.5.v20081205.jar,
 libs/junit-4.5.jar,
 libs/dsn.jar,
 libs/imap.jar,
 libs/mailapi.jar,
 libs/smtp.jar,
 libs/jnotify-0.93.jar,
 libs/groovy-all-1.7.6.jar,
 libs/joda-time-2.0.jar,
 libs/commons-io-2.0.1.jar
Bundle-Activator: com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.main.Activator
Export-Package: ca.odell.glazedlists,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.event,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.gui,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.adt,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.adt.barcode2,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.adt.gnutrove,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.beans,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.ctp,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.filter,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.gui,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.io,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.java15,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.matchers,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.nio,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.pmap,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.rbp,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.sort,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.swing,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.swt,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.io,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.jfreechart,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.matchers,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.migrationkit,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.migrationkit.swing,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.migrationkit.swt,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.nachocalendar,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.swing,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.swt,
 ca.odell.glazedlists.util.concurrent,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.config.common,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.config.extensions,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.config.generators.common,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.core,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.core.configs,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.core.extensions,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.core.jobs,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.core.logging,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.core.preferences,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.exception,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.model,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.model.common,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.model.extensions,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.model.interfaces,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.model.utils,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.properties,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.actions.common,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.common,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.common.ui,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.common.ui.actionicons,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.common.ui.components,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.dialogs.common,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.dialogs.components,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.dialogs.components.validators,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.dialogs.editors,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.dialogs.misc,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.editors.appmap,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.extensions,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.gef.actions,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.gef.common,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.gef.editpolicies,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.gef.extensions,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.gef.figures.common,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.gef.parts,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.gef.parts.common,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.main,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.views,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.views.common,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.rcp.views.logs,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.security.providers.extensions,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.services.providers.extensions,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.tools,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.tools.compare,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.tools.groovy,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.utils.misc,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.utils.misc.convert,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.utils.misc.xml,
 javax.activation,
 javax.mail,
 javax.xml.bind,
 javax.xml.bind.annotation,
 javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters,
 javax.xml.bind.attachment,
 javax.xml.bind.helpers,
 javax.xml.bind.util,
 net.miginfocom.swt,
 org.apache.log4j,
 org.apache.log4j.spi,
 org.apache.xml.serializ
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Bundle-Vendor: mycompany

**Module1 Manifest**
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: mysoftware mycompany Module1 Plug-in
*Bundle-SymbolicName: com.mycompany.mysoftware.mycompanyModule1;singleton:=true*
Bundle-Version: 2.7.2.qualifier
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: com.mycompany.mysoftware.deps.mycompany
Bundle-Activator: com.mycompany.mysoftware.mycompanyModule1.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 *com.mycompany.mysoftware.core,*
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.weblogic,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.shares,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.deps.mycompany,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.jboss,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.jee,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.deps.jboss
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 libs/commons-collections-3.2.jar,
 libs/groovy-all-1.7.6.jar,
 libs/velocity-1.7.jar,
 libs/commons-lang-2.4.jar,
 libs/axis-1.4.jar,
 libs/commons-discovery-0.2.jar
Bundle-Vendor: mycompany
Export-Package: com.mycompany.mysoftware.mycompanyModule1.cmdb,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.mycompanyModule1.jboss,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.mycompanyModule1.jboss.deployment,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.mycompanyModule1.jmx.engine,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.mycompanyModule1.naming,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.mycompanyModule1.network,
 org.apache.commons.collections

**Module2 Manifest**
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: mysoftware mycompany Module2
*Bundle-SymbolicName: com.mycompany.mysoftware.mycompanyModule2;singleton:=true*
Bundle-Version: 2.7.2.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.mycompany.mysoftware.mycompanyModule2.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: mycompany & Cie
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 *com.mycompany.mysoftware.core,*
 org.eclipse.gef,
 com.mycompany.mysoftware.deps.jboss
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Export-Package: com.mycompany.mysoftware.mycompanyModule2
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 libs/junit-4.5.jar

Adding the dependency just adds on line in the "Require-Bundle" section of the Module2 manifest, with the symbolic name of Module1.

Comment: Are you using a target platform? Is the plugin included?

Comment: I haven't repackaged my project yet, everything happens in Eclipse.

Comment: Would you please post the manifests for each plugin (with an without the dependency)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-exporting the dependency on core from m1 to m2?
You can do this my opening the manifest editor for m1, then in the dependencies tab, select core and click the properties button. There is then an option to re-export the plugin's code.

E.g., if you have `m2 <- m1 <- core`, then re-exporting core dependencies 'through' m1 should make them visible in m2.

Hope this helps